# How to list post of certain category (only one category lets say cat id = 5 ) only on blog listing page?

Tags: wordpress, post, hook

I need to list posts of certain category only on blog listing page , let's say of category id 5. I need it to do from plugins or function.php file. I do not want to change the template files, i think blog listing is on index.php.

I used parse_query hook like following. But is affect other places as well . The menu bar is gone. Please help me. Thank you.

```
 add_filter( 'parse_query', 'pp_posts_filter' );

  function pp_posts_filter( $query ){

    $query->query_vars['cat'] = 5;
  }
```

Comment: You need to add conditional for Main Query i.e. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the query changes specific to main query only and not secondary ones like Menus or Sidebars etc. Use is_main_query function i.e.

```
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_exclude_category' );
function foo_modify_query_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->get( 'cat' ) )
        $query->set( 'cat', '-5' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mohsin . It is great. Worked

Comment: Glad you got it working @RockyPrajapati. Happy coding! :) You may mark this as resolved.